# Generate Randomized Color Board

Tags: python, random, index-error

generate a random (height x width) grid such that for every coordinate (i, j), there can be no three consecutive same colors in a row or in a column.

generate(int: width, int: height, list: colors)

Example:

```
getvalidMatrix(3, 3, [0, 1, 2])

output:

[

[1, 2, 1],

[1, 0, 2],

[0, 1, 2],

]
```

```
import random
def getvalidMatrix(length,width,colors):
    map = dict()
    
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        map[colors[i]]=i
        
    res = [[0] * length] * width
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(width):
            end = len(colors)
            if i - 1 >= 0 and i - 2 >= 0 and res[i-1][j] == res[i-2][j]:
                index = map[res[i-1][j]]
                colors[index] = colors[end]
                colors[end] = map[res[i-1]][j]
                end -= 1
            if j - 1 >= 0 and j - 2 >= 0 and res[i][j-1] == res[i][j-2]:
                index = map[res[i][j-1]]
                colors[index] = colors[end]
                colors[end] = map[res[i][j-1]]
                end -= 1
            next=random.randint(0,end)
            res[i][j] = colors[next]
            
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 3
    width = 3
    colors = [0,1,2]
    print(getvalidMatrix(length, width, colors))
```

I got IndexError: list index out of range with the code above. Which part of the code should I fix in order to avoid the IndexError?

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't completely understand de algorithm used to solve the problem, I can see that you are committing a few mistakes:

1. You're retrieving a multidimensional list element incorrectly, e.g., `list_var[a][b]` instead of `list_var[b][a]`. This can be solved in the for loops.
2. You're indexing variable `colors` this way: `colors[end] = ...`, but variable `end` is initialized as `end = len(colors)`, i.e., with a value 1 unit greater than the maximum index allowed, remember that lists are zero-indexed.
3. A misplaced closing bracket.

Here's the corrected code. Run a file diff to see the changes I've made. I don't guarantee it now solves the problem you were given but the errors you came across are gone.

```
import random
def getvalidMatrix(length,width,colors):
    map = dict()
    
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        map[colors[i]]=i
        
    res = [[0] * length] * width
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(length):
            end = len(colors)-1
            if i - 1 >= 0 and i - 2 >= 0 and res[i-1][j] == res[i-2][j]:
                index = map[res[i-1][j]]
                colors[index] = colors[end]
                colors[end] = map[res[i-1][j]]
                end -= 1
            if j - 1 >= 0 and j - 2 >= 0 and res[i][j-1] == res[i][j-2]:
                index = map[res[i][j-1]]
                colors[index] = colors[end]
                colors[end] = map[res[i][j-1]]
                end -= 1
            next=random.randint(0,end)
            res[i][j] = colors[next]
            
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 3
    width = 3
    colors = [0,1,2]
    print(getvalidMatrix(length, width, colors))
```